# Help me calculate integral $J=\int_{C} y^{2}z^{2}dx + x^{2}z^{2}dy + x^{2}y^{2}dz$ using Stokes theorem

Tags: integration, contour-integration, stokes-theorem

Task: Calculate integral using stokes theorem.

I'm getting stack in calculating the integral
$$J=\int_{C} y^{2}z^{2}dx + x^{2}z^{2}dy + x^{2}y^{2}dz$$
where
$$C:
\begin{cases}
x&=a\cos(t)\\
y&=a\cos(2t)\\
z&=a\cos(3t).
\end{cases}
$$
and $a=const$ we should integrate increasing t.
The answer is 0.
Please, give me some hints, because I'm new to this kind of integrals and it's quite difficult for me to understand it. Or if you can solve it with explanation. Thanks everyone.

Comment: To apply Stokes Theorem you need a surface of which the curve $ C $ is the boundary.

Comment: kieran is correct. The first thing you need to do is find a surface that $C$ is the boundary of. Note that $\cos 2t = 2\cos^t -1$ and $\cos 3t = 4\cos^3 t - \cos t$. So $y$ and $z$ are both uniquely determined by the value of $x$. You can use to find a suitable surface. For example, you could choose the surface $$(x,z) \mapsto (x, \frac 2a x^2 - a, z)$$